# Calculating working hours for everyday for every worker using excel and python Dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, datetime

i have an excel file that records every time a worker check's in and out of the office during the day using a column that takes two values "entrer" is check in/ "sortie" is check out,
i need to calculate how much time the worker stayed in the office for every day in the month and if the worker forgot to check in just add a column to the table with the value "anomaly".

now i got it working for one day of the week 100% and the whole file also but as soon i have to separate by day and month to calculate the total hours it just spits out errors and i have to remove the grouping by ID but then the count is no good.

this is my code right now:

```
df = pd.read_excel("./fp.xls")
df = df.sort_values("Date And Time")
regEx = r'^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$'
    
for x,n in enumerate(df.values[1]):
    if bool(re.match(regEx,str(n))):
        df[df.columns[x]] = pd.to_datetime(df[df.columns[x]])
      
results = [part for _, part in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date And Time',freq='1D'))] 

#this is the grouping by id that i didn't know how to use wit the date
group = df.groupby("Personnel ID")

# dates =group.apply(lambda x: x['Date And Time'].unique())
zz=pd.Timedelta(0)
lam=[]
res=[]
for x in results:
    # print(x["Event Point"])
    if len(x)%2!=0:
        print("anomaly")
    else:
        lam.append(x)
        
for i in range(0,len(lam)):
    if(len(lam[i])==0):
        print("weekend")
    else:
        for y in lam[i].values:
            status = y[2]
            if status == "Entree":
                hh = y[0]
            else:
                kk=y[0]-hh
                zz=zz+kk
        print(pd.to_datetime(lam[i].values[0][0]).date(),lam[i].values[0][1],zz)
        zz=pd.Timedelta(0)
```

this is the data for one day:

```
{'Date And Time': {0: '2020-10-15 18:59:18', 1: '2020-10-15 18:23:28', 2: '2020-10-15 18:21:01', 3: '2020-10-15 14:02:11', 4: 
'2020-10-15 14:02:08', 5: '2020-10-15 13:51:34', 6: '2020-10-15 12:22:51', 7: '2020-10-15 12:07:39', 8: '2020-10-15 12:05:21', 9: '2020-10-15 12:02:31', 10: '2020-10-15 10:24:37', 11: '2020-10-15 09:02:51', 12: '2020-10-15 08:54:57', 13: '2020-10-15 08:44:10', 14: '2020-10-15 08:15:31'}, 'Personnel ID': {0: 44, 1: 41, 2: 43, 3: 43, 4: 44, 5: 41, 6: 44, 7: 41, 8: 41, 9: 43, 10: 42, 11: 42, 12: 43, 13: 44, 14: 41}, 'Event Point': {0: 'Sortie', 1: 'Sortie', 2: 'Sortie', 3: 'Entree', 4: 'Entree', 5: 'Entree', 6: 'Sortie', 7: 'Sortie', 8: 'Sortie', 9: 'Sortie', 10: 
'Sortie', 11: 'Entree', 12: 'Entree', 13: 'Entree', 14: 'Entree'}}
```

and here for two months:

```
{'Date And Time': {0: '2020-09-23 18:11:05', 1: '2020-09-23 18:01:58', 2: '2020-09-23 18:01:52', 3: '2020-09-23 18:01:47', 4: '2020-09-23 14:12:16', 5: '2020-09-23 14:06:12', 6: '2020-09-23 13:46:43', 7: '2020-09-23 13:27:54', 8: '2020-09-23 12:07:59', 9: '2020-09-23 12:07:46', 10: '2020-09-23 12:04:50', 11: '2020-09-23 12:04:42', 12: '2020-09-23 08:46:20', 13: '2020-09-23 08:45:14', 14: '2020-09-23 08:40:54', 15: '2020-09-23 08:15:36', 16: '2020-09-22 18:15:29', 17: '2020-09-22 18:15:27', 18: '2020-09-22 18:14:45', 19: '2020-09-22 18:11:13', 20: '2020-09-22 14:17:49', 21: '2020-09-22 14:08:03', 22: '2020-09-22 14:05:55', 23: '2020-09-22 13:56:38', 24: '2020-09-22 12:33:23', 25: '2020-09-22 12:05:23', 26: '2020-09-22 12:04:13', 27: '2020-09-22 12:04:12', 28: '2020-09-22 08:51:03', 29: '2020-09-22 08:46:39', 30: '2020-09-22 08:35:43', 31: '2020-09-22 08:04:49', 32: '2020-09-21 18:12:05', 33: '2020-09-21 18:11:57', 34: '2020-09-21 18:11:49', 35: '2020-09-21 18:11:38', 36: '2020-09-21 14:07:34', 37: '2020-09-21 14:07:06', 38: '2020-09-21 14:04:33', 39: '2020-09-21 13:44:54', 40: '2020-09-21 12:20:47', 41: '2020-09-21 12:20:42', 42: '2020-09-21 12:18:42', 43: '2020-09-21 12:06:53', 44: '2020-09-21 08:53:35', 45: '2020-09-21 08:43:28', 46: '2020-09-21 08:43:26', 47: '2020-09-21 08:43:23', 48: '2020-09-21 08:02:12', 49: '2020-09-18 17:59:45', 50: '2020-09-18 17:59:39', 51: '2020-09-18 17:59:37', 52: '2020-09-18 17:55:39', 53: '2020-09-18 14:05:58', 54: '2020-09-18 14:02:50', 55: '2020-09-18 13:56:56', 56: '2020-09-18 13:21:58', 57: '2020-09-18 12:07:35', 58: '2020-09-18 12:06:20', 59: '2020-09-18 12:06:19', 60: '2020-09-18 12:03:41', 61: '2020-09-18 08:46:57', 62: '2020-09-18 08:43:50', 63: '2020-09-18 08:37:18', 64: '2020-09-18 08:17:51', 65: '2020-09-17 18:20:35', 66: '2020-09-17 18:03:24', 67: '2020-09-17 18:03:00', 68: '2020-09-17 15:30:39', 69: '2020-09-17 14:10:28', 70: '2020-09-17 14:06:52', 71: '2020-09-17 14:03:15', 72: '2020-09-17 12:15:34', 73: '2020-09-17 12:14:56', 74: '2020-09-17 12:14:50', 75: '2020-09-17 12:05:10', 76: '2020-09-17 08:56:54', 77: '2020-09-17 08:48:09', 78: '2020-09-17 08:36:53', 79: '2020-09-16 18:06:03', 80: '2020-09-16 18:05:38', 81: '2020-09-16 18:02:12', 82: '2020-09-16 17:22:34', 83: '2020-09-16 17:14:08', 84: '2020-09-16 14:07:49', 85: '2020-09-16 14:05:24', 86: '2020-09-16 14:00:05', 87: '2020-09-16 13:27:24', 88: '2020-09-16 12:16:30', 89: '2020-09-16 12:06:31', 90: '2020-09-16 12:06:21', 91: '2020-09-16 12:04:38', 92: '2020-09-16 08:46:13', 93: '2020-09-16 08:45:01', 94: '2020-09-16 08:41:41', 95: '2020-09-16 08:07:57', 96: '2020-09-15 18:05:33', 97: '2020-09-15 18:05:31', 98: '2020-09-15 18:03:37', 99: '2020-09-15 18:03:17', 100: '2020-09-15 14:20:40', 101: '2020-09-15 14:08:49', 102: '2020-09-15 13:59:10', 103: '2020-09-15 13:57:10', 104: '2020-09-15 12:46:12', 105: '2020-09-15 12:16:59', 106: '2020-09-15 12:16:46', 107: '2020-09-15 12:06:08', 108: '2020-09-15 12:05:30', 109: '2020-09-15 08:44:48', 110: '2020-09-15 08:42:40', 111: '2020-09-15 08:32:25', 112: '2020-09-15 08:05:41', 113: '2020-09-14 18:24:39', 114: '2020-09-14 18:24:28', 115: '2020-09-14 18:24:25', 116: '2020-09-14 18:21:59', 117: '2020-09-14 15:54:49', 118: '2020-09-14 14:24:58', 119: '2020-09-14 14:11:24', 120: '2020-09-14 14:07:22', 121: '2020-09-14 12:01:31', 122: '2020-09-14 12:01:28', 123: '2020-09-14 12:00:57', 124: '2020-09-14 11:25:14', 125: '2020-09-14 11:14:10', 126: '2020-09-14 08:45:52', 127: '2020-09-14 08:45:50', 128: '2020-09-14 08:40:20', 129: '2020-09-11 18:03:14', 130: '2020-09-11 18:00:52', 131: '2020-09-11 14:15:25', 132: '2020-09-11 14:09:48', 133: '2020-09-11 13:53:59', 134: '2020-09-11 12:04:33', 135: '2020-09-11 12:04:07', 136: '2020-09-11 08:45:38', 137: '2020-09-11 08:24:43', 138: '2020-09-10 18:15:37', 139: '2020-09-10 18:15:35', 140: '2020-09-10 18:10:08', 141: '2020-09-10 16:57:51', 142: '2020-09-10 16:45:37', 143: '2020-09-10 14:09:46', 144: '2020-09-10 13:57:23', 145: '2020-09-10 13:44:19', 146: '2020-09-10 12:14:35', 147: '2020-09-10 11:58:47', 148: '2020-09-10 09:50:05', 149: '2020-09-10 09:35:04', 150: '2020-09-10 08:48:23', 151: '2020-09-10 08:42:14', 152: '2020-09-10 08:15:31', 153: '2020-09-09 18:10:21', 154: '2020-09-09 18:10:13', 155: '2020-09-09 18:10:04', 156: '2020-09-09 18:01:47', 157: '2020-09-09 14:31:18', 158: '2020-09-09 14:01:18', 159: '2020-09-09 14:00:27', 160: '2020-09-09 13:39:51', 161: '2020-09-09 12:03:06', 162: '2020-09-09 12:03:04', 163: '2020-09-09 11:59:39', 164: '2020-09-09 11:57:19', 165: '2020-09-09 08:46:50', 166: '2020-09-09 08:44:19', 167: '2020-09-09 08:32:32', 168: '2020-09-09 08:07:07', 169: '2020-09-08 17:57:33', 170: '2020-09-08 17:57:18', 171: '2020-09-08 17:57:13', 172: '2020-09-08 17:54:38', 173: '2020-09-08 14:05:16', 174: '2020-09-08 14:04:59', 175: '2020-09-08 13:54:21', 176: '2020-09-08 13:41:54', 177: '2020-09-08 12:14:47', 178: '2020-09-08 12:14:44', 179: '2020-09-08 12:08:23', 180: '2020-09-08 12:01:40', 181: '2020-09-08 08:43:23', 182: '2020-09-08 08:43:10', 183: '2020-09-08 08:27:24', 184: '2020-09-08 08:04:59', 185: '2020-09-07 18:20:15', 186: '2020-09-07 18:19:01', 187: '2020-09-07 18:16:15', 188: '2020-09-07 17:58:54', 189: '2020-09-07 14:09:42', 190: '2020-09-07 14:07:07', 191: '2020-09-07 14:02:48', 192: '2020-09-07 14:02:31', 193: '2020-09-07 12:07:24', 194: '2020-09-07 12:07:22', 195: '2020-09-07 12:02:32', 196: '2020-09-07 11:58:33', 197: '2020-09-07 08:46:11', 198: '2020-09-07 08:41:10', 199: '2020-09-07 08:39:18', 200: '2020-09-07 08:01:50', 201: '2020-09-04 17:59:57', 202: '2020-09-04 17:55:19', 203: '2020-09-04 17:54:32', 204: '2020-09-04 17:54:25', 205: '2020-09-04 16:05:20', 206: '2020-09-04 14:11:30', 207: '2020-09-04 14:09:26', 208: '2020-09-04 14:04:35', 209: '2020-09-04 11:59:00', 210: '2020-09-04 11:58:56', 211: '2020-09-04 11:55:15', 212: '2020-09-04 08:52:33', 213: '2020-09-04 08:47:47', 214: '2020-09-04 08:40:39', 215: '2020-09-04 08:21:50', 216: '2020-09-04 08:05:18', 217: '2020-09-03 18:59:50', 218: '2020-09-03 18:59:48', 219: '2020-09-03 18:38:27', 220: '2020-09-03 17:57:14', 221: '2020-09-03 17:35:48', 222: '2020-09-03 17:20:15', 223: '2020-09-03 14:14:02', 224: '2020-09-03 13:59:30', 225: '2020-09-03 13:59:27', 226: '2020-09-03 13:24:34', 227: '2020-09-03 12:14:29', 228: '2020-09-03 12:14:10', 229: '2020-09-03 12:12:53', 230: '2020-09-03 12:02:28', 231: '2020-09-03 11:41:33', 232: '2020-09-03 09:43:46', 233: '2020-09-03 08:48:49', 234: '2020-09-03 08:42:45', 235: '2020-09-03 08:20:12', 236: '2020-09-03 08:08:36', 237: '2020-09-02 18:15:22', 238: '2020-09-02 18:15:20', 239: '2020-09-02 17:53:53', 240: '2020-09-02 14:10:58', 241: '2020-09-02 13:48:23', 242: '2020-09-02 13:29:09', 243: '2020-09-02 12:12:32', 244: '2020-09-02 12:10:34', 245: '2020-09-02 12:03:34', 246: '2020-09-02 08:46:33', 247: '2020-09-02 08:36:43', 248: '2020-09-02 08:12:36', 249: '2020-09-01 18:32:59', 250: '2020-09-01 18:19:36', 251: '2020-09-01 14:01:17', 252: '2020-09-01 13:49:08', 253: '2020-09-01 12:31:19', 254: '2020-09-01 12:03:16', 255: '2020-09-01 08:35:43', 256: '2020-09-01 08:30:01', 257: '2020-08-31 18:30:32', 258: '2020-08-31 18:21:44', 259: '2020-08-31 18:20:16', 260: '2020-08-31 17:32:19', 261: '2020-08-31 14:08:09', 262: '2020-08-31 13:59:47', 263: '2020-08-31 12:22:35', 264: '2020-08-31 12:02:21', 265: '2020-08-31 08:43:36', 266: '2020-08-31 08:27:49', 267: '2020-08-28 18:25:17', 268: '2020-08-28 18:15:43', 269: '2020-08-28 18:08:52', 270: '2020-08-28 17:15:30', 271: '2020-08-28 14:14:15', 272: '2020-08-28 14:12:24', 273: '2020-08-28 14:12:04', 274: '2020-08-28 13:54:11', 275: '2020-08-28 12:13:58', 276: '2020-08-28 12:13:56', 277: '2020-08-28 12:04:25', 278: '2020-08-28 11:57:17', 279: '2020-08-28 08:40:08', 280: '2020-08-28 08:39:15', 281: '2020-08-28 08:26:37', 282: '2020-08-28 08:18:56', 283: '2020-08-27 18:28:29', 284: '2020-08-27 18:28:25', 285: '2020-08-27 18:28:00', 286: '2020-08-27 18:16:39', 287: '2020-08-27 17:06:13', 288: '2020-08-27 16:51:08', 289: '2020-08-27 14:12:45', 290: '2020-08-27 14:07:19', 291: '2020-08-27 13:58:51', 292: '2020-08-27 13:28:47', 293: '2020-08-27 12:13:24', 294: '2020-08-27 12:13:21', 295: '2020-08-27 12:10:04', 296: '2020-08-27 12:01:29', 297: '2020-08-27 11:25:12', 298: '2020-08-27 08:44:47', 299: '2020-08-27 08:37:17', 300: '2020-08-27 08:21:51', 301: '2020-08-26 18:23:42', 302: '2020-08-26 18:02:09', 303: '2020-08-26 18:02:04', 304: '2020-08-26 17:46:49', 305: '2020-08-26 16:21:28', 306: '2020-08-26 15:23:51', 307: '2020-08-26 14:11:54', 308: '2020-08-26 14:08:07', 309: '2020-08-26 13:49:31', 310: '2020-08-26 13:43:04', 311: '2020-08-26 12:05:58', 312: '2020-08-26 12:04:42', 313: '2020-08-26 12:02:19', 314: '2020-08-26 11:59:11', 315: '2020-08-26 10:56:36', 316: '2020-08-26 10:32:39', 317: '2020-08-26 08:44:29', 318: '2020-08-26 08:39:17', 319: '2020-08-26 08:20:23', 320: '2020-08-26 08:00:39', 321: '2020-08-25 18:02:48', 322: '2020-08-25 17:38:40', 323: '2020-08-25 17:38:35', 324: '2020-08-25 16:39:59', 325: '2020-08-25 16:29:54', 326: '2020-08-25 14:13:16', 327: '2020-08-25 14:05:58', 328: '2020-08-25 13:51:39', 329: '2020-08-25 12:17:55', 330: '2020-08-25 12:17:52', 331: '2020-08-25 12:00:30', 332: '2020-08-25 08:40:26', 333: '2020-08-25 08:36:28', 334: '2020-08-25 08:28:43', 335: '2020-08-24 18:09:50', 336: '2020-08-24 18:08:48', 337: '2020-08-24 14:12:10', 338: '2020-08-24 13:46:25', 339: '2020-08-24 12:03:57', 340: '2020-08-24 12:03:38', 341: '2020-08-24 08:41:10', 342: '2020-08-24 08:07:33', 343: '2020-08-19 17:45:54', 344: '2020-08-19 14:01:46', 345: '2020-08-19 11:58:31', 346: '2020-08-19 09:37:37', 347: '2020-08-18 19:26:12', 348: '2020-08-18 15:08:31', 349: '2020-08-18 12:57:16', 350: '2020-08-18 09:46:00', 351: '2020-08-17 19:04:35', 352: '2020-08-17 14:03:39', 353: '2020-08-17 12:00:07', 354: '2020-08-17 08:45:19', 355: '2020-08-13 18:33:15', 356: '2020-08-13 18:22:00', 357: '2020-08-13 18:19:52', 358: '2020-08-13 14:21:03', 359: '2020-08-13 13:52:57', 360: '2020-08-13 13:18:46', 361: '2020-08-13 13:15:07', 362: '2020-08-13 12:25:10', 363: '2020-08-13 08:35:16', 364: '2020-08-13 08:34:25', 365: '2020-08-13 07:51:18', 366: '2020-08-12 19:04:16', 367: '2020-08-12 18:21:48', 368: '2020-08-12 18:21:45', 369: '2020-08-12 18:11:21', 370: '2020-08-12 16:03:08', 371: '2020-08-12 15:37:15', 372: '2020-08-12 15:16:53', 373: '2020-08-12 15:01:02', 374: '2020-08-12 14:05:57', 375: '2020-08-12 14:05:56', 376: '2020-08-12 13:50:11', 377: '2020-08-12 13:43:08', 378: '2020-08-12 12:16:47', 379: '2020-08-12 12:16:46', 380: '2020-08-12 11:59:56', 381: '2020-08-12 11:55:00', 382: '2020-08-12 11:34:49', 383: '2020-08-12 11:34:47', 384: '2020-08-12 11:30:15', 385: '2020-08-12 08:39:24', 386: '2020-08-12 08:28:24', 387: '2020-08-12 08:15:23', 388: '2020-08-11 18:02:46', 389: '2020-08-11 18:02:27', 390: '2020-08-11 18:00:38', 391: '2020-08-11 17:58:35', 392: '2020-08-11 14:03:41', 393: '2020-08-11 14:01:29', 394: '2020-08-11 13:56:08', 395: '2020-08-11 13:30:10', 396: '2020-08-11 12:38:57', 397: '2020-08-11 12:19:28', 398: '2020-08-11 12:19:15', 399: '2020-08-11 11:59:24', 400: '2020-08-11 11:51:12', 401: '2020-08-11 08:31:01', 402: '2020-08-11 08:31:00', 403: '2020-08-11 08:27:52', 404: '2020-08-10 23:24:25', 405: '2020-08-10 22:21:44', 406: '2020-08-10 22:17:45', 407: '2020-08-10 21:11:37', 408: '2020-08-10 20:00:09', 409: '2020-08-10 18:18:54', 410: '2020-08-10 18:16:40', 411: '2020-08-10 18:02:07', 412: '2020-08-10 14:59:06', 413: '2020-08-10 14:07:31', 414: '2020-08-10 14:05:17', 415: '2020-08-10 14:02:26', 416: '2020-08-10 12:14:18', 417: '2020-08-10 12:14:01', 418: '2020-08-10 12:02:52', 419: '2020-08-10 11:59:06', 420: '2020-08-10 11:55:53', 421: '2020-08-10 11:10:55', 422: '2020-08-10 10:41:08', 423: '2020-08-10 08:35:53', 424: '2020-08-10 08:34:11', 425: '2020-08-10 08:03:27', 426: '2020-08-07 18:38:30', 427: '2020-08-07 18:07:28', 428: '2020-08-07 18:07:22', 429: '2020-08-07 18:07:19', 430: '2020-08-07 17:59:29', 431: '2020-08-07 14:06:25', 432: '2020-08-07 14:06:18', 433: '2020-08-07 13:58:06', 434: '2020-08-07 12:23:07', 435: '2020-08-07 12:22:56', 436: '2020-08-07 12:00:48', 437: '2020-08-07 08:37:22', 438: '2020-08-07 08:31:57', 439: '2020-08-07 08:08:26', 440: '2020-08-06 18:47:41', 441: '2020-08-06 18:25:58', 442: '2020-08-06 18:07:21', 443: '2020-08-06 18:06:25', 444: '2020-08-06 16:15:31', 445: '2020-08-06 14:07:27', 446: '2020-08-06 13:59:40', 447: '2020-08-06 13:53:46', 448: '2020-08-06 13:47:37', 449: '2020-08-06 13:14:54', 450: '2020-08-06 12:10:44', 451: '2020-08-06 12:03:07', 452: '2020-08-06 12:02:44', 453: '2020-08-06 11:58:53', 454: '2020-08-06 08:28:57', 455: '2020-08-06 08:25:59', 456: '2020-08-06 08:12:37', 457: '2020-08-06 08:11:22', 458: '2020-08-05 18:38:54', 459: '2020-08-05 18:20:40', 460: '2020-08-05 18:20:38', 461: '2020-08-05 18:20:32', 462: '2020-08-05 14:02:37', 463: '2020-08-05 13:54:04', 464: '2020-08-05 13:36:11', 465: '2020-08-05 13:07:56', 466: '2020-08-05 12:33:28', 467: '2020-08-05 12:27:42', 468: '2020-08-05 12:27:34', 469: '2020-08-05 12:21:09', 470: '2020-08-05 10:58:44', 471: '2020-08-05 08:35:38', 472: '2020-08-05 08:27:57', 473: '2020-08-05 08:14:06', 474: '2020-08-04 18:22:47', 475: '2020-08-04 18:22:45', 476: '2020-08-04 18:22:43', 477: '2020-08-04 16:55:41', 478: '2020-08-04 16:44:36', 479: '2020-08-04 16:26:28', 480: '2020-08-04 16:24:56', 481: '2020-08-04 14:07:33', 482: '2020-08-04 14:05:45', 483: '2020-08-04 14:02:30', 484: '2020-08-04 12:14:52', 485: '2020-08-04 12:14:50', 486: '2020-08-04 12:09:57', 487: '2020-08-04 08:35:58', 488: '2020-08-04 08:33:16', 489: '2020-08-04 08:15:55'}, 'Personnel ID': {0: 41, 1: 43, 2: 44, 3: 42, 4: 44, 5: 43, 6: 42, 7: 41, 8: 44, 9: 42, 10: 43, 11: 41, 12: 44, 13: 43, 14: 42, 15: 41, 16: 44, 17: 42, 18: 41, 19: 43, 20: 42, 21: 44, 22: 43, 23: 41, 24: 42, 25: 41, 26: 43, 27: 44, 28: 44, 29: 43, 30: 42, 31: 41, 32: 44, 33: 41, 34: 42, 35: 43, 36: 44, 37: 42, 38: 43, 39: 41, 40: 44, 41: 42, 42: 41, 43: 43, 44: 43, 45: 44, 46: 44, 47: 42, 48: 41, 49: 43, 50: 44, 51: 42, 52: 41, 53: 44, 54: 43, 55: 42, 56: 41, 57: 41, 58: 44, 59: 42, 60: 43, 61: 43, 62: 44, 63: 42, 64: 41, 65: 42, 66: 43, 67: 41, 68: 41, 69: 44, 70: 42, 71: 43, 72: 44, 73: 44, 74: 42, 75: 43, 76: 44, 77: 43, 78: 42, 79: 44, 80: 42, 81: 43, 82: 44, 83: 44, 84: 44, 85: 43, 86: 42, 87: 41, 88: 41, 89: 44, 90: 42, 91: 43, 92: 43, 93: 44, 94: 42, 95: 41, 96: 44, 97: 42, 98: 41, 99: 43, 100: 42, 101: 44, 102: 43, 103: 41, 104: 42, 105: 44, 106: 44, 107: 41, 108: 43, 109: 44, 110: 43, 111: 42, 112: 41, 113: 44, 114: 42, 115: 43, 116: 41, 117: 41, 118: 42, 119: 44, 120: 43, 121: 42, 122: 44, 123: 43, 124: 42, 125: 42, 126: 43, 127: 42, 128: 44, 129: 42, 130: 41, 131: 41, 132: 44, 133: 42, 134: 44, 135: 42, 136: 44, 137: 42, 138: 44, 139: 42, 140: 41, 141: 44, 142: 44, 143: 44, 144: 42, 145: 41, 146: 42, 147: 41, 148: 41, 149: 41, 150: 44, 151: 42, 152: 41, 153: 42, 154: 41, 155: 44, 156: 43, 157: 44, 158: 41, 159: 43, 160: 42, 161: 44, 162: 42, 163: 43, 164: 41, 165: 44, 166: 43, 167: 42, 168: 41, 169: 44, 170: 42, 171: 43, 172: 41, 173: 44, 174: 43, 175: 42, 176: 41, 177: 44, 178: 42, 179: 41, 180: 43, 181: 44, 182: 43, 183: 42, 184: 41, 185: 44, 186: 42, 187: 41, 188: 43, 189: 44, 190: 43, 191: 42, 192: 41, 193: 42, 194: 44, 195: 43, 196: 41, 197: 44, 198: 42, 199: 43, 200: 41, 201: 41, 202: 44, 203: 42, 204: 43, 205: 41, 206: 43, 207: 44, 208: 42, 209: 44, 210: 43, 211: 42, 212: 41, 213: 44, 214: 43, 215: 42, 216: 41, 217: 43, 218: 42, 219: 44, 220: 41, 221: 44, 222: 44, 223: 44, 224: 42, 225: 43, 226: 41, 227: 44, 228: 42, 229: 41, 230: 43, 231: 41, 232: 41, 233: 44, 234: 43, 235: 42, 236: 41, 237: 43, 238: 42, 239: 41, 240: 43, 241: 42, 242: 41, 243: 41, 244: 42, 245: 43, 246: 43, 247: 42, 248: 41, 249: 42, 250: 43, 251: 43, 252: 42, 253: 42, 254: 43, 255: 43, 256: 42, 257: 41, 258: 43, 259: 42, 260: 41, 261: 43, 262: 42, 263: 42, 264: 43, 265: 43, 266: 42, 267: 41, 268: 42, 269: 43, 270: 44, 271: 41, 272: 44, 273: 43, 274: 42, 275: 42, 276: 44, 277: 41, 278: 43, 279: 43, 280: 44, 281: 42, 282: 41, 283: 41, 284: 44, 285: 42, 286: 43, 287: 44, 288: 44, 289: 44, 290: 41, 291: 42, 292: 43, 293: 44, 294: 42, 295: 41, 296: 43, 297: 41, 298: 43, 299: 44, 300: 42, 301: 41, 302: 44, 303: 43, 304: 42, 305: 41, 306: 41, 307: 44, 308: 43, 309: 42, 310: 41, 311: 44, 312: 42, 313: 43, 314: 41, 315: 41, 316: 41, 317: 43, 318: 44, 319: 42, 320: 41, 321: 43, 322: 44, 323: 42, 324: 44, 325: 44, 326: 44, 327: 43, 328: 42, 329: 42, 330: 44, 331: 43, 332: 42, 333: 43, 334: 44, 335: 42, 336: 43, 337: 43, 338: 42, 339: 42, 340: 43, 341: 43, 342: 42, 343: 43, 344: 43, 345: 43, 346: 43, 347: 43, 348: 43, 349: 43, 350: 43, 351: 43, 352: 43, 353: 43, 354: 43, 355: 41, 356: 42, 357: 43, 358: 43, 359: 41, 360: 41, 361: 41, 362: 44, 363: 43, 364: 44, 365: 42, 366: 41, 367: 44, 368: 42, 369: 43, 370: 44, 371: 44, 372: 41, 373: 41, 374: 44, 375: 43, 376: 41, 377: 42, 378: 44, 379: 42, 380: 43, 381: 44, 382: 44, 383: 44, 384: 44, 385: 44, 386: 43, 387: 42, 388: 44, 389: 42, 390: 43, 391: 41, 392: 44, 393: 43, 394: 42, 395: 41, 396: 41, 397: 44, 398: 42, 399: 43, 400: 41, 401: 44, 402: 43, 403: 42, 404: 41, 405: 41, 406: 41, 407: 41, 408: 41, 409: 44, 410: 42, 411: 43, 412: 41, 413: 42, 414: 44, 415: 43, 416: 44, 417: 42, 418: 42, 419: 43, 420: 42, 421: 41, 422: 41, 423: 44, 424: 43, 425: 42, 426: 41, 427: 43, 428: 42, 429: 44, 430: 41, 431: 43, 432: 44, 433: 42, 434: 44, 435: 42, 436: 43, 437: 44, 438: 43, 439: 42, 440: 43, 441: 41, 442: 44, 443: 42, 444: 41, 445: 44, 446: 43, 447: 41, 448: 42, 449: 41, 450: 41, 451: 44, 452: 42, 453: 43, 454: 43, 455: 44, 456: 41, 457: 42, 458: 41, 459: 44, 460: 43, 461: 42, 462: 44, 463: 42, 464: 41, 465: 43, 466: 43, 467: 44, 468: 42, 469: 41, 470: 41, 471: 44, 472: 43, 473: 42, 474: 43, 475: 42, 476: 44, 477: 44, 478: 44, 479: 43, 480: 43, 481: 44, 482: 43, 483: 42, 484: 42, 485: 44, 486: 43, 487: 44, 488: 43, 489: 42}, 'Event Point': {0: 'Sortie', 1: 'Sortie', 2: 'Sortie', 3: 'Sortie', 4: 'Entree', 5: 'Entree', 6: 'Entree', 7: 'Entree', 8: 'Sortie', 9: 'Sortie', 10: 'Sortie', 11: 'Sortie', 12: 'Entree', 13: 'Entree', 14: 'Entree', 15: 'Entree', 16: 'Sortie', 17: 'Sortie', 18: 'Sortie', 19: 'Sortie', 20: 'Entree', 21: 'Entree', 22: 'Entree', 23: 'Entree', 24: 'Sortie', 25: 'Sortie', 26: 'Sortie', 27: 'Sortie', 28: 'Entree', 29: 'Entree', 30: 'Entree', 31: 'Entree', 32: 'Sortie', 33: 'Sortie', 34: 'Sortie', 35: 'Sortie', 36: 'Entree', 37: 'Entree', 38: 'Entree', 39: 'Entree', 40: 'Sortie', 41: 'Sortie', 42: 'Sortie', 43: 'Sortie', 44: 'Entree', 45: 'Entree', 46: 'Entree', 47: 'Entree', 48: 'Entree', 49: 'Sortie', 50: 'Sortie', 51: 'Sortie', 52: 'Sortie', 53: 'Entree', 54: 'Entree', 55: 'Entree', 56: 'Entree', 57: 'Sortie', 58: 'Sortie', 59: 'Sortie', 60: 'Sortie', 61: 'Entree', 62: 'Entree', 63: 'Entree', 64: 'Entree', 65: 'Sortie', 66: 'Sortie', 67: 'Sortie', 68: 'Entree', 69: 'Entree', 70: 'Entree', 71: 'Entree', 72: 'Sortie', 73: 'Sortie', 74: 'Sortie', 75: 'Sortie', 76: 'Entree', 77: 'Entree', 78: 'Entree', 79: 'Sortie', 80: 'Sortie', 81: 'Sortie', 82: 'Entree', 83: 'Sortie', 84: 'Entree', 85: 'Entree', 86: 'Entree', 87: 'Entree', 88: 'Sortie', 89: 'Sortie', 90: 'Sortie', 91: 'Sortie', 92: 'Entree', 93: 'Entree', 94: 'Entree', 95: 'Entree', 96: 'Sortie', 97: 'Sortie', 98: 'Sortie', 99: 'Sortie', 100: 'Entree', 101: 'Entree', 102: 'Entree', 103: 'Entree', 104: 'Sortie', 105: 'Sortie', 106: 'Sortie', 107: 'Sortie', 108: 'Sortie', 109: 'Entree', 110: 'Entree', 111: 'Entree', 112: 'Entree', 113: 'Sortie', 114: 'Sortie', 115: 'Sortie', 116: 'Sortie', 117: 'Entree', 118: 'Entree', 119: 'Entree', 120: 'Entree', 121: 'Sortie', 122: 'Sortie', 123: 'Sortie', 124: 'Entree', 125: 'Sortie', 126: 'Entree', 127: 'Entree', 128: 'Entree', 129: 'Sortie', 130: 'Sortie', 131: 'Entree', 132: 'Entree', 133: 'Entree', 134: 'Sortie', 135: 'Sortie', 136: 'Entree', 137: 'Entree', 138: 'Sortie', 139: 'Sortie', 140: 'Sortie', 141: 'Entree', 142: 'Sortie', 143: 'Entree', 144: 'Entree', 145: 'Entree', 146: 'Sortie', 147: 'Sortie', 148: 'Entree', 149: 'Sortie', 150: 'Entree', 151: 'Entree', 152: 'Entree', 153: 'Sortie', 154: 'Sortie', 155: 'Sortie', 156: 'Sortie', 157: 'Entree', 158: 'Entree', 159: 'Entree', 160: 'Entree', 161: 'Sortie', 162: 'Sortie', 163: 'Sortie', 164: 'Sortie', 165: 'Entree', 166: 'Entree', 167: 'Entree', 168: 'Entree', 169: 'Sortie', 170: 'Sortie', 171: 'Sortie', 172: 'Sortie', 173: 'Entree', 174: 'Entree', 175: 'Entree', 176: 'Entree', 177: 'Sortie', 178: 'Sortie', 179: 'Sortie', 180: 'Sortie', 181: 'Entree', 182: 'Entree', 183: 'Entree', 184: 'Entree', 185: 'Sortie', 186: 'Sortie', 187: 'Sortie', 188: 'Sortie', 189: 'Entree', 190: 'Entree', 191: 'Entree', 192: 'Entree', 193: 'Sortie', 194: 'Sortie', 195: 'Sortie', 196: 'Sortie', 197: 'Entree', 198: 'Entree', 199: 'Entree', 200: 'Entree', 201: 'Sortie', 202: 'Sortie', 203: 'Sortie', 204: 'Sortie', 205: 'Entree', 206: 'Entree', 207: 'Entree', 208: 'Entree', 209: 'Sortie', 210: 'Sortie', 211: 'Sortie', 212: 'Sortie', 213: 'Entree', 214: 'Entree', 215: 'Entree', 216: 'Entree', 217: 'Sortie', 218: 'Sortie', 219: 'Sortie', 220: 'Sortie', 221: 'Entree', 222: 'Sortie', 223: 'Entree', 224: 'Entree', 225: 'Entree', 226: 'Entree', 227: 'Sortie', 228: 'Sortie', 229: 'Sortie', 230: 'Sortie', 231: 'Entree', 232: 'Sortie', 233: 'Entree', 234: 'Entree', 235: 'Entree', 236: 'Entree', 237: 'Sortie', 238: 'Sortie', 239: 'Sortie', 240: 'Entree', 241: 'Entree', 242: 'Entree', 243: 'Sortie', 244: 'Sortie', 245: 'Sortie', 246: 'Entree', 247: 'Entree', 248: 'Entree', 249: 'Sortie', 250: 'Sortie', 251: 'Entree', 252: 'Entree', 253: 'Sortie', 254: 'Sortie', 255: 'Entree', 256: 'Entree', 257: 'Sortie', 258: 'Sortie', 259: 'Sortie', 260: 'Entree', 261: 'Entree', 262: 'Entree', 263: 'Sortie', 264: 'Sortie', 265: 'Entree', 266: 'Entree', 267: 'Sortie', 268: 'Sortie', 269: 'Sortie', 270: 'Sortie', 271: 'Entree', 272: 'Entree', 273: 'Entree', 274: 'Entree', 275: 'Sortie', 276: 'Sortie', 277: 'Sortie', 278: 'Sortie', 279: 'Entree', 280: 'Entree', 281: 'Entree', 282: 'Entree', 283: 'Sortie', 284: 'Sortie', 285: 'Sortie', 286: 'Sortie', 287: 'Entree', 288: 'Sortie', 289: 'Entree', 290: 'Entree', 291: 'Entree', 292: 'Entree', 293: 'Sortie', 294: 'Sortie', 295: 'Sortie', 296: 'Sortie', 297: 'Entree', 298: 'Entree', 299: 'Entree', 300: 'Entree', 301: 'Sortie', 302: 'Sortie', 303: 'Sortie', 304: 'Sortie', 305: 'Entree', 306: 'Sortie', 307: 'Entree', 308: 'Entree', 309: 'Entree', 310: 'Entree', 311: 'Sortie', 312: 'Sortie', 313: 'Sortie', 314: 'Sortie', 315: 'Entree', 316: 'Sortie', 317: 'Entree', 318: 'Entree', 319: 'Entree', 320: 'Entree', 321: 'Sortie', 322: 'Sortie', 323: 'Sortie', 324: 'Entree', 325: 'Sortie', 326: 'Entree', 327: 'Entree', 328: 'Entree', 329: 'Sortie', 330: 'Sortie', 331: 'Sortie', 332: 'Entree', 333: 'Entree', 334: 'Entree', 335: 'Sortie', 336: 'Sortie', 337: 'Entree', 338: 'Entree', 339: 'Sortie', 340: 'Sortie', 341: 'Entree', 342: 'Entree', 343: 'Sortie', 344: 'Entree', 345: 'Sortie', 346: 'Entree', 347: 'Sortie', 348: 'Entree', 349: 'Sortie', 350: 'Entree', 351: 'Sortie', 352: 'Entree', 353: 'Sortie', 354: 'Entree', 355: 'Sortie', 356: 'Sortie', 357: 'Sortie', 358: 'Entree', 359: 'Entree', 360: 'Sortie', 361: 'Entree', 362: 'Sortie', 363: 'Entree', 364: 'Entree', 365: 'Entree', 366: 'Sortie', 367: 'Sortie', 368: 'Sortie', 369: 'Sortie', 370: 'Entree', 371: 'Sortie', 372: 'Entree', 373: 'Sortie', 374: 'Entree', 375: 'Entree', 376: 'Entree', 377: 'Entree', 378: 'Sortie', 379: 'Sortie', 380: 'Sortie', 381: 'Entree', 382: 'Entree', 383: 'Sortie', 384: 'Sortie', 385: 'Entree', 386: 'Entree', 387: 'Entree', 388: 'Sortie', 389: 'Sortie', 390: 'Sortie', 391: 'Sortie', 392: 'Entree', 393: 'Entree', 394: 'Entree', 395: 'Entree', 396: 'Sortie', 397: 'Sortie', 398: 'Sortie', 399: 'Sortie', 400: 'Entree', 401: 'Entree', 402: 'Entree', 403: 'Entree', 404: 'Sortie', 405: 'Entree', 406: 'Sortie', 407: 'Entree', 408: 'Sortie', 409: 'Sortie', 410: 'Sortie', 411: 'Sortie', 412: 'Entree', 413: 'Entree', 414: 'Entree', 415: 'Entree', 416: 'Sortie', 417: 'Sortie', 418: 'Entree', 419: 'Sortie', 420: 'Sortie', 421: 'Sortie', 422: 'Entree', 423: 'Entree', 424: 'Entree', 425: 'Entree', 426: 'Sortie', 427: 'Sortie', 428: 'Sortie', 429: 'Sortie', 430: 'Entree', 431: 'Entree', 432: 'Entree', 433: 'Entree', 434: 'Sortie', 435: 'Sortie', 436: 'Sortie', 437: 'Entree', 438: 'Entree', 439: 'Entree', 440: 'Sortie', 441: 'Sortie', 442: 'Sortie', 443: 'Sortie', 444: 'Entree', 445: 'Entree', 446: 'Entree', 447: 'Sortie', 448: 'Entree', 449: 'Entree', 450: 'Sortie', 451: 'Sortie', 452: 'Sortie', 453: 'Sortie', 454: 'Entree', 455: 'Entree', 456: 'Entree', 457: 'Entree', 458: 'Sortie', 459: 'Sortie', 460: 'Sortie', 461: 'Sortie', 462: 'Entree', 463: 'Entree', 464: 'Entree', 465: 'Entree', 466: 'Sortie', 467: 'Sortie', 468: 'Sortie', 469: 'Sortie', 470: 'Entree', 471: 'Entree', 472: 'Entree', 473: 'Entree', 474: 'Sortie', 475: 'Sortie', 476: 'Sortie', 477: 'Entree', 478: 'Sortie', 479: 'Entree', 480: 'Sortie', 481: 'Entree', 482: 'Entree', 483: 'Entree', 484: 'Sortie', 485: 'Sortie', 486: 'Sortie', 487: 'Entree', 488: 'Entree', 489: 'Entree'}}
```

and thank you very much i have been stuck here for two days!!!

Comment: Does your posted code work as desired for a single day?  What variable holds your desired result?  It does same to do much when I run it.

Comment: @DarrylG in the current state no since to make it work for one day i need to remove the code to iterate on every day for it to work for the whole periode,but here is it if you want to try
`zz=pd.Timedelta(0)
lam=[]
res=[]
for x in group:
    # print(x["Event Point"])
    if len(x[1])%2!=0:
        print("anomaly")
    # else:
    lam.append(x[1])
        
`
this is part one

Comment: this is part two:

`for i in range(0,len(lam)):
    if(len(lam[i])==0):
        print("weekend")
    else:
        for y in lam[i].values:
            status = y[2]
            if status == "Entree":
                st="Entree"
                hh = y[0]
            else:
                if st!="Sortie":
                    st="Sortie"
                    kk=y[0]-hh
                    zz=zz+kk
        print(pd.to_datetime(lam[i].values[0][0]).date(),lam[i].values[0][1],zz)
        zz=pd.Timedelta(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you could try the following code.  The code use NaN for cases where there is an issue with Entree/Sortie times.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def hours_worked(tf):
    '''
        Find the elapsed time between accumulated Entree/Sortie in DataFrame
        
        Return nan when there is a issue with start/stop times
    '''
    start = tf['Event Point']=='Entree'
    stop =  tf['Event Point']=='Sortie'
    if start.sum() == stop.sum():   # Check that we have a matching number of Entree & Sortie
        starts = tf[start]['date_time']
        stops = tf[stop]['date_time']
        
        if (stops.values >= starts.values ).all():
            elapsed = (stops.values - starts.values).sum()
            # Return value hours
            return elapsed.astype('timedelta64[s]').astype(np.int32)/3600.
        else:
            # Not all Entree/Sortie pairs, not all start times are greater than corresponding stop time
            return np.nan
    else:
        # Number of Entree/Sortie doesn't match
        return np.nan
    
def agg_daily(tf):
    '''
        Aggregate hours worked by day and personnel ID
    
    '''
    return (tf
            .assign(date_time = pd.to_datetime(tf['Date And Time'])) # Convert string to Date & time
            .sort_values(['date_time'])                       # Sort by datetimes together
            .groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date_time',freq='1D'),  # Group by Day
                   'Personnel ID'])                           # and ID
            .apply(hours_worked)                              # Get hours worked           
            .to_frame()                                       # To Dataframe
            .rename(columns = {0:"Hours Worked"}))            # renaming column 0

def agg_monthly(df):
    '''
        Aggregates data in df on monthly basis
    '''
    # Aggregate daily
    daily = agg_daily(df).reset_index()
    
    # Aggregate daily to monthy
    return (daily
             .groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date_time',freq='M'),  # Group by Month
                               'Personnel ID'])                           # and ID
             .sum())
```

**Usage**

```
result = agg_daily(df)     # Aggregate hours daily for dataframe df
result = agg_monthly(df)   # Aggregates result month
```

**Test Results**

Using posted data from the question.

*Test 1*
Using 1 day of data

```
pp(agg_daily(df))          # print daily aggregation
pp(agg_monthly(df))        # print monthly aggregation

                         Hours Worked
date_time  Personnel ID              
2020-10-15 41                     NaN
           42                1.362778
           43                7.440000
           44                8.597500
                         Hours Worked
date_time  Personnel ID              
2020-10-31 41                0.000000
           42                1.362778
           43                7.440000
           44                8.597500
```

*Test 2*
Multiple days of data

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)   # Prevents truncating of DataFrame rows in print (i.e. pp)
pp(agg_daily(df))          # print daily aggregation
pp(agg_monthly(df))        # print monthly aggregation
 

                         Hours Worked
date_time  Personnel ID              
2020-08-04 42                8.320000
           43                7.869722
           44                7.715833
2020-08-05 41                6.418889
           42                8.665556
           43                9.303611
           44                8.168611
2020-08-06 41                6.790556
           42                8.169444
           43                8.299167
           44                7.617222
2020-08-07 41                0.650278
           42                8.396111
           43                7.498333
           44                7.779444
2020-08-10 41                7.660833
           42                8.212222
           43                7.410000
           44                7.867222
2020-08-11 41                5.269444
           42                7.961667
           43                7.459167
           44                7.792222
2020-08-12 41                4.970556
           42                8.666667
           43                7.615833
           44                     NaN
2020-08-13 41                4.732500
           42               10.511667
           43                     NaN
           44                3.845833
2020-08-17 43                8.262222
2020-08-18 43                7.482500
2020-08-19 43                6.083889
2020-08-24 42                8.330278
           43                7.318333
2020-08-25 42                7.406944
           43                7.347778
           44                7.074444
2020-08-26 41                7.293333
           42                7.693611
           43                7.196389
           44                7.282222
2020-08-27 41                5.100556
           42                8.344167
           43                8.076111
           44                7.611667
2020-08-28 41                7.941944
           42                8.148056
           43                7.232500
           44                6.629722
2020-08-31 41                0.970278
           42                8.254167
           43                7.538889
2020-09-01 42                8.752500
           43                7.764444
2020-09-02 41                8.411111
           42                8.013333
           43                7.356944
2020-09-03 41                6.652778
           42                8.904444
           43                8.335000
           44                7.575556
2020-09-04 41                2.697778
           42                7.389444
           43                7.020000
           44                6.951667
2020-09-07 41                8.174167
           42                7.707500
           43                7.250278
           44                7.528889
2020-09-08 41                8.268889
           42                7.838056
           43                7.178889
           44                7.394722
2020-09-09 41                7.985278
           42                8.017222
           43                7.277778
           44                6.917222
2020-09-10 41                7.901111
           42                7.842500
           44                     NaN
2020-09-11 41                3.757500
           42                7.810833
           44                     NaN
2020-09-14 41                2.452778
           42                7.068611
           43                7.535556
           44                7.573056
2020-09-15 41                8.115000
           42                7.977222
           43                7.449167
           44                     NaN
2020-09-16 41                     NaN
           42                7.503611
           43                7.253611
           44                7.188333
2020-09-17 41                2.539167
           42                7.861111
           43                7.286111
           44                     NaN
2020-09-18 41                8.390278
           42                7.528333
           43                7.227500
           44                7.269722
2020-09-21 41                8.725833
           42                7.700556
           43                7.339722
           44                     NaN
2020-09-22 41                8.311389
           42                7.921667
           43                7.381111
           44                7.343056
2020-09-23 41                8.538056
           42                7.698889
           43                7.256111
           44                7.187500
                         Hours Worked
date_time  Personnel ID              
2020-08-31 41               57.799167
           42              117.080556
           43              121.994444
           44               79.384444
2020-09-30 41              100.921111
           42              133.535833
           43              110.912222
           44               72.929722
```

Comment: Thank you veery much i got the same results using a janky spaghetti code witch is not optimized at all and won't work in some cases,this is 10 times better. but i am still struggling with the total of every month for every worker part without needing to redo everything.

Comment: @ayoubnay -- glad it helped.  I'll take a look at aggregating by month when I get a break.  It shouldn't be that difficult.  Would you want the information in another column of the same table or a separate table?

Comment: if it's possible at the end of every month but if it's messy or hard you can put it in another table (if possible to do both if it's not more work but no pressure).
and again thank youu very much boss just threw this at me in my last week as an intern.

Comment: @ayoubnay --Take a look at my update.  I added as a 2nd table since there was the simplest.  But, let me know if you really prefer in the same table.

Comment: thank you very much i did try to just concat the two dataframes but if you have a better solution and it's not much trouble yes please.

Comment: @ayoubnay another dea is to try with `pd.concat([daily, monthly], axis = 1, keys = ['Daily', 'Monthly'])`, where `daily = agg_daily(df);  monthly = agg_monthly(df)`

Comment: i actualy did the same thing res = pd.concat([daily,monthly ]) . but now he only wants the months he is driving me nuts. but thank you very much for all the help man

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247221/discussion-between-darrylg-and-ayoub-nay).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247226/discussion-between-nayn9-and-darrylg).

Comment: i sent a message